# Why Google robots.txt Tester has error and it's not valid

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console

As you can see in below image **Google WebMaster Tools** robots.txt Tester tell me about 9 error but I don't know how to fix it and what is the problem?
[image]

Please help me to figure out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a valid robots.txt - but you've got a [UTF-8 BOM (\xef\xbb\xbf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the text file. That's why there's a red dot next to 'User' in the first line. This mark tells browsers and text editors to interpret the file as UTF-8 whereas the robots.txt is expected to use only ASCII characters.

Convert your text file to ASCII and the errors will go away. Or copy everything after the red dot and try pasting it in again.

I tested this on the live version, here's the result translated from byte form:

```
\xef\xbb\xbfUser-agent: *\r\nDisallow: /en/news/iranology/\r\nDisallow:
 /en/tours-services/tour-the-soul-of-iran\r\nDisallow: 
/en/tours-services/tour-a-whistle-stop-tour\r\nDisallow: /en/to
```

You can clearly see the BOM at the beginning. Browsers and text editors will ignore it but it may mess with a crawlers ability to parse the robots.txt. You can test the live version using this python script:

```
import urllib.request

text = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.best-iran-trip.com/robots.txt')

print(repr(text.read()))
```

If you're able to install [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), it actually has an encoding menu that lets you save it in any format.

Comment: Dear Yhorian please let me to check and I will tell you the result. I created this file in Windows and notepad.exe, So how can I see UTF BOM and detect it?

Comment: I think it's better to edit your answer and add a solution for me and other users to fix this

Comment: If you're on windows, I recommend using notepad++ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It has an 'encoding' menu that lets you just click the one you want to save it in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use webmaster panel tools 
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool
and test your robots file then download it

it works ok.

[image]

Comment: I found the correct answer as you can see at top. The problem was file encoding